# Fetch documents from multiple subcollections - Firebase

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a web app for admin with firebase integration, this web app is used by admin to monitor posts or comments posted by user from Android or iOS app developed in ionic.

I'm using Firebase firestore, and following is the database design
`posts/{postsDocument}/comments/{commentsDocument}`.

The `comments` here is sub-collection for postsDocument that holds all the comments for a particular post. Also `postDocument` and `commentsDocument` contains Firebase uid of the user.

My problem is, whether it's possible to fetch all the comments commented by a particular user. I can query a single collection, but in this scenario commentsDocument is a subcollection and i want to fetch all comments across all the post by a user for monitoring purpose.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the edits, much cleaner now. I will try to format questions next time onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check firebase [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)

```
var commentsQuery = db.collectionGroup('comments').where('commentOwnerID', '==', userId);//userId - firebase id of the user who commented
commentsQuery.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});
```

Also you might have to create index that supports your query, check console for the the link for creating index

Comment: That worked for me, Group query I didn't look into. Thank Ked